# Pip ignores specific package requirements from a dependency

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I'm using `pip` to install a package that will require `protobuf` from multiple dependencies using different versions' requirements.

`pip` outputs this error
[image]

Using `pipdeptree` i can see that no package requires a version of `protobuf` higher than 4.0 but `toto.lightstep`requires a version of `protobuf` lower than 4.0

```
toto-wrapper==0.2.0
  - toto-protobuf [required: >=0.0.2, installed: 0.0.2]
    - protobuf [required: Any, installed: 4.21.5]
  - toto.lightstep [required: Any, installed: 1.4.1]
        - protobuf [required: >=3.0.0b2.post2, installed: 4.21.5]
        - protobuf [required: >=3.15.0,<5.0.0dev, installed: 4.21.5]
      - protobuf [required: >=3.6.0,<4.0, installed: 4.21.5]
  - protobuf [required: Any, installed: 4.21.5]
```

Isn't `pip` supposed to resolve this kind of requirement to install just the right version?

Edit: This happens on a fresh new environment `protobuf` isn't installed prior `lightstep`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually due to an old version of pip `20.0.2`. Upgrading to `22.2.2` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It is likely the case that `protobuf` was installed before `toto.lightstep` and so pip has a newer version than is allowed. I would suggest either:

1. Uninstall `protobuf` before installing `toto.lightstep`, or
2. Pin `protobuf` to <4.0 in your requirements

Comment: Isn't pip supposed to resolve all dependencies before choosing a version of a package ? So that it can pick the one that matches the best all the requirements ?

Comment: @bertrand my understanding is that if `protobuf` is already installed before you install `toto.lightstep` then pip will throw up its hands. Pip will only do backtracking on packages it can instal during a dependency resolution. Pip won’t go uninstalling your already installed packages while it is installing others.

Comment: Sorry i'll clarify that in the problem description but it's happening on a fresh virtual environment